# How to run the project after import to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded the source code from git hub and I imported the project to Eclipse but I don't know how to execute this project because I am a beginner. Please tell me how to execute this project.

[image]

Comment: Find the class which had main class --> right click --> run as --> java application

Comment: You always need to run it with the class which contains main method. though its important to know what kind of project is it like maven, gradle, ant etc. By knowing this you can build the project and then run it. Let me know if you need more details on it.

Comment: It is ant build project

Answer (score 0):

if your program has a class with a main method in it you can run it by pressing the green circle with the play icon in the top left of eclipse.

Comment: Just find a video on youtube